# stopping user to access the system for few days

Tags: linux, ubuntu

One of our user is on leave for few days 
and I want to stop him accessing the systems for these days ..

should I

```
        Add * to his encrypted password 

       or delete the user from  etc /password file
       or Remove the user encrypted password
       or rename username to root
       or set his userID to -1
```

Which option should i go for out of the above

Comment: can we assume that anyone from the internet can access?

Comment: adding a * to /etc/password will not do anything if he has Keyless SSH access, if this is in some application which uses a database for authentication then he may be able to reset his password if he really needs to. 


I think you should edit this question to include more information instead of "the systems"

Comment: If this is simply for a DATABASE, then DENY access to the database user. If this 'access' is via another means then *use the appropriate method, whatever it is*.

Answer (score 0):

It's for an access to a Linux system (Ubuntu). Not sure where you found those listed options, but in general try to use the system's tools to manage the system.

Simply lock the account:

```
sudo passwd -l [user_name]
```

Alternatively you can put an expire date on the account:

```
sudo passwd -e  YYYY-MM-DD [user_name]
```

To unlock a locked account:

```
sudo passwd -u [username]
```

Comment: you think , adding * to the encrypted password will also work?

Comment: Might work, not sure. I would recommend using system tools to accomplish those tasks. If you just want to lock the account, simply use the command to do that. Why hacking?